# How does WHERE clause work (interchanging LHS and RHS)

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I tried the following query in MySQL,

```
select first_name from my_contacts WHERE 'Blunt' = last_name;
```

and it works fine.

Just like,

```
select first_name from my_contacts WHERE last_name = 'Blunt';
```

So how does `WHERE` clause work . I assumed when it encounters a `WHERE` it expects it to be followed by a column name and RHS of `=` with a value (In this case a String).

But it seems even interchanging LHS and RHS is fine. Is it similar to `if(a == 1)` or `if(1 == a)` in C or C++ (Doesn't matter which is RHS or LHS)?

**Note:** If there are links that can help me in this matter pls do include them

Comment: use "explain" before your query, it will explain it

Comment: I learn every day here.. =)

Comment: actually you can do `WHERE 'a' = 'a'`. WHERE just takes predicates/conditions. Equality is symmetric, thus you can switch the operands without affecting the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much like a compiler does with C source code, MySQL (or any database) **parses** the query text and uses the syntax tree to create something it can execute, a query plan, namely. MySQL is figuring out what the query means piece by piece, and it uses a grammar like any programming language to try to figure out what each part is. As Borniet notes, we are allowed to put even a constant expression inside a where clause. We could also compare two columns for equality. This is because MySQL allows `WHERE` to use any expression with a result that can be coerced into to a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed very much comparable to an IF statement:

```
WHERE (statement that needs to be true) AND (a = 1) OR (B = 2)
```

So you could also do:

```
WHERE 1
```